# jquery data do not match dom attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jquery-data

I have an weird issue with jquery data function. Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mqZMD/)

As you can see I update the `active` data but I cannot see the dom `data-active` attribute value change, although I re-query the active data, It writes the changed value.
$.data() do not update the attribute on the dom when I inspect it.

Comment: `.data()` and attributes are not the same thing. jQuery just happens to make all `data-*` attributes available by `.data()`. If you manipulate `.data()`, it doesn't change the attribute. If you manipulate the attribute, it does change the `.data()`. Also, just as a note, instead of `$($('li')[1])`, you can use `$("li").eq(1)` - you don't have to re-wrap it in a jQuery object

Comment: I always just use `.attr('data-'+data,value)` and `.attr('data-'+data)`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7262427/1414562

Answer (score 6, accepted):

jQuery `data` api does not depends on the element attribute although it uses `data-<key>` to fetch the initial value if it is available.

jQuery uses an internal javascript object to maintain the data value of objects

If you want to update the `attribute` then you will have to use `.attr('data-<key>', '<value>')`

Comment: Appreciated for explanation. However, what is the point of using `.data` function then? I can query but not update, this inconsistency can create weird behaviours for inexperienced users of jq. I'd rather use the very same function for both query and update. Is there a reasonable explanation for that?

Comment: @px5x2 you can update as well as query the data :) only problem is the attribute value will not get updated, the updated value is stored as a key-value construct by jQuery

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use `attr` as `.data` will not update the actual DOM node attribute -

```
$($('li')[1]).attr('data-active', true);
```

- http://api.jquery.com/data/